# Pycharm .wav file unrecognized

Tags: audio, pycharm, speech-recognition, wav, pyaudio

I'm having trouble working with a .wav file in Pycharm. I'm following a YouTube video on speech recognition but the editor I'm using it's recognizing the file type. Is there a addon I'm supposed to install so that the file is recognized?
[image]